# rmarkdown spanish accents within inline code

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an Rmd with many Spanish accents, I have no problems with the evaluation but the code is displayed as comments because of the accents. For instance, in the code below everything after "Funcionarios públicos" is shown in green as the comments.  How can I fix this?

````
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "AUTHOR"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r , eval=F, include=T}



conflict <- conflict %>% 
  mutate(ocupacionvictima=ifelse(ocupacionvictima=="Funcionarios públicos ", 
                             "Funcionarios públicos", ocupacionvictima)) %>% 
  mutate(periodo2=ifelse(annoh>=1958 & annoh<=1976, "1958-1976", 
                    ifelse(annoh>=1977 & annoh<=1990, "1977-1990", 
                           ifelse(annoh>=1991 & annoh<=2001, "1991-2001", 
                                  ifelse(annoh>=2002 & annoh<=2015,"2002-2015", "2016")))))


```
````

Comment: It works fine for me when I run it